# TxPower not changing

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I am trying to change the TxPower of my beacons but I am not able to do it.
My beacon has 3 values for TxPower 00,01 and 02.The TxPower received is same for all of these values.Any suggestions?The beacons follow iBeacon protocol.I am parsing the byte array "data" as follows:int txpower=data[29];Setting txpower through lightblue app of iPhone

Comment: What do you mean your "beacon has 3 values for TxPower"?  An iBeacon transmission contains only a single value.  It may be useful to clarify the manufacturer of the beacon, as configuration of beacons through apps like LightBlue (i.e. using GATT) is outside the iBeacon spec and is different for every beacon manufacturer.

Comment: I meant three values are given by manufacturer for txpower...we can set any 1.I am using Lightblue app to set txpower.I think some issue with the beacon hardware.

Comment: What is the beacon made del?  Does the manufacturer recommend using LightBlue?

Comment: I found my mistake..I missed the concept of measured power completely.Now,I get different Measured Power at different values of TxPower..